# At what point do I return the data from this query?

Tags: node.js, tedious

I have this method for querying a database with an event on row.  How do I know when all rows have been iterated through?

I'm not sure when you return when all rows have been processed.  The below code seems to cause issues.

```
 getData : function(data){
    var connection = new Connection(config);
    var newdata = [];
    var dataset = [];
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo."+data.entity+" WHERE "+data.field+" LIKE '%"+data.params+"%'";

        var Request = require('tedious').Request;
        var request = new Request(sql, function (err, rowCount) {
            if (err) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if (rowCount < 1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        request.on('row', function(columns) {

            columns.forEach(function(column) {
                   dataset.push({
                       col: column.metadata.colName,
                       val: column.value
                   });


            });

            newdata.push(dataset);

        });

        request.on('done', function(){
            //connection.close();
            return newdata;
        })

        connection.execSql(request);

    });

},
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just `return` from asynchronous code, you need to use a callback. Pass a `callback` parameter into your `getData` function and then call it in `Request`s callback.

Also, according to the [docs](http://pekim.github.io/tedious/api-request.html), you shouldn't be listening to the `done` event; you should just use `Request`'s callback. Relevant bit:

> This is a relatively low-level event, driven by the
>   receipt of a TDS Done token. Most uses of Tedious can ignore this
>   event, and should rely on the Request's callback function to know when
>   the request has completed.

With that in mind, you'll want to do something like this:

```
getData : function(data, callback){
    var connection = new Connection(config);
    var newdata = [];
    var dataset = [];
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {

        var sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo."+data.entity+" WHERE "+data.field+" LIKE '%"+data.params+"%'";

        var Request = require('tedious').Request;
        var request = new Request(sql, function (err, rowCount) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
            } else {
                if (rowCount < 1) {
                    callback(null, false);
                } else {
                    callback(null, newdata);
                }
            }
        });

        request.on('row', function(columns) {

            columns.forEach(function(column) {
                   dataset.push({
                       col: column.metadata.colName,
                       val: column.value
                   });


            });

            newdata.push(dataset);

        });

        connection.execSql(request);

    });

}
```

Then to call it, you'd do:

```
getData(data, function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle the error
    } else if (rows) {
        // Process the rows returned from the database
    } else {
        // No rows returns; handle appropriately
    }
});
```